# Select All apart from objects with specific name in Maya using Python

Tags: python, maya

I would like to select all *deletable* objects in my Maya scene apart from a set of Joints that start with the name JOINT_GAME

This is so that when I come to export the file, I can be sure the file is nice and clean and only contains what I need.

So far I have some code to make an array of joints to keep called 'JointsForExport'

```
#--- Select Joints for export then invert 

cmds.select(clear=True)
JointsForExport = cmds.ls("JOINT_GAME*")

for val in JointsForExport:
    cmds.select(val, add = True)
```

The next step I can't seem to work out is how to delete everything in the scene that isn't in this group

Comment: The tricky part here will be figuring out whats 'non-deletable' -- you have the usual stuff like the default lights and cameras, but plugins or containers can also add things which will generate errors.

If you're doing this for an exporter, a common trick is to make a new namespace and duplicate what you want to export into it, then select the entire namespace and export, then delete that.  That way if you want to do export time changes to the data the originals are untouched

Answer (score 1):

```
JointsForExport = cmds.ls("JOINT_GAME*")
all = cmds.ls()

difference = list(set(all)-set(JointsForExport))

cmds.select(difference)
```

Note that you shouldn't loop for select, i might be really slow :

```
for val in JointsForExport:
    cmds.select(val, add = True)
```

should be :

```
cmds.select(JointsForExport)
```

Comment: hi! Unfortunately this doesn't give me the result I want. Joints that begin with JOINT_GAME are still selected

Comment: huuum maybe, you have to use type flag in ls : cmds.ls("JOINT_GAME*", type='joint') and if you need transforms, do a cmds.listRelatives(jointList, p=True), maybe you have to exclude some node as groups. Also can you print the result of difference to see if there is the joints in it

Comment: Depending on how he's got that set up he may also be selecting the parents of the joints he wants